# how ieee 802.11s does channel switching? is it supported?

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11, ieee-802.1s, mesh

I'm studying about IEEE 802.11s wireless mesh networks
every where on documents i read is pointed that all Mesh Point must be on same channel for discovery and peering.

But i can't find anything about channel switchings after peering.

Is the selected channel permanent over the time?
does 802.11s support channel switching? what happens if channel get noisy or congested? is there any mechanism for ieee 802.11s to change the channel which MBSS is working at?

Comment: Changing the channel breaks the peering.

Comment: @ron-maupin: so in 802.11s channel is fixed and static? and it can not change it if one channel get noise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about how that will fail. Each device has a radio, and if a WAP is connected to other WAPs then they must share a channel. If they use a channel, and a new WAP peers with one of them on that channel, and the new WAP and its peer change to a different channel, the the peer of the other WAPs will no longer be connected to the other WAPs because it is now on a different channel.

WAP A can see WAPs B and C, B and C cannot see each other, so the are peered through WAP A, and they are peered on channel 6. WAP D comes up and can see WAP A, and it peers with WAP A on channel 6, peering with WAPs B and C through WAP A. WAP D then asks WAP A to change to channel 1. If the peering between WAP A and WAP D changes to channel 1, the entire peering gets broken if WAP A changes to a different channel because WAPs B and C are bow orphaned from WAPs A and D and each other.

Each has only one radio, and it can only use one channel. If WAP A changes its channel to peer with a different WAP, it breaks its peering with its existing peers because it can no longer hear or talk to those older peers.